# Problem with wireless network menu gnome-shell

Tags: wireless, gnome

**Original Title:** *Problema con el menu de redes inalambricas de gnome-shell*

**Basic english translatation (via Google Translate + edited by hand):**
Today I found a problem with the gnome GUI shell and I would like to help me solve it, the question is: how I can disconnect from a wireless network using the classic menu of networks? (that which is in the top right of the bar), for example if I connect a usb wireless card, the network manager detects my internal wireless card and the external but it's going to automatically connect to the same networks on the two cards and I just want to disconnect from an order not to have conflicts between them, but gnome shell allows me to disable the wireless adapter, but does not work because I've tried and I am still connected. I do not understand because the shell no longer has the button that said ''off''. Is there any way to revive the ''off'' button in gnome shell or does only Unity retain that button?

**original**

hoy me encontré con un problema con la interfaz gráfica gnome shell y me gustaría que me ayuden a resolverlo, la duda es: ¿como puedo desconectarme de una red inalámbrica usando el clásico menú de redes? (aquel que se encuentra en la parte superior a la derecha de la barra), por ejemplo si conecto una tarjeta inalámbrica usb, el network manager detectará mi tarjeta inalámbrica interna y también el externo pero éste automáticamente me va a conectar a la misma red con las dos tarjetas y lo que quiero es desconectarme de una para así no tener conflictos entre ambas, el gnome shell me permite desactivar el adaptador inalámbrico pero no sirve porque ya lo he probado y sigue conectado, lo que no entiendo porque el gnome shell ya no trae ese botón que decía ''desconectar'' .
¿Hay alguna manera de reactivar ese botón ''desconectar'' en gnome shell o solo unity mantiene ese boton?

Answer (score 1):

Yo probé el mismo montaje, pero dejé usar la tarjeta WLAN USB porque ahora mi tarjeta interna está perfectamente configurada y usando ambas me deja la conección más lenta. Te pregunto ¿porque quieres ambas tarjetas enchufadas sin estar conectado con ambas? Si quieres conectarte a una red con una y otra red con la segunda tarjeta, debería funcionar. Si quieres estar conectado a una red con sólo una tarjeta, mejor desenchufar la otra. Si quieres simplemente tener ambas enchufadas pero usar sólo una tarjeta a la vez, es posible desactivar la otra con el interruptor gráfico en el menú de conecciones internet del Gnome Shell. Ese interruptor sirve para "desconectar". Luego lo puedes activar con el mismo interruptor y conectarte a la misma red o a otra.

Now in English. I've tried pretty much the same thing, but I stopped using my USB WLAN card because I've got the internal WLAN card nicely configured, and using both makes my connection slow. I have to ask, why do you want both WLAN cards connected to your computer without using both simultaneously? If you connect to one network with one card and another network with your 2nd WLAN card, it should work fine. If you want both WLAN cards connected to your computer yet only want to use one at a time, the one you don't wish to use, you can simply use the "switch" in the network applet in Gnome Shell. That switch can be set to "off" (the exact word from your Babelfish translation), but it won't say "disconnect". Afterwards you can re-enable the WLAN card and connect to the same network or a different one by setting that switch back to "on".